# Regular Expression to match both first characters and last character in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with a column with the structure:
Table name : re_result

```
res_id 
--------------
PSI8765450
PSIRRRRTY781
ABCD000001
```

I want to fetch the values starting with PSI and ending with 1. My expected output is PSIRRRRTY781.

I am using query

```
Select * from re_result
Where regexp_like(^PSI*1)
```

But I am not getting the output. I am getting both PSIRRRRTY781 and ABCD000001.

Plz help

Answer (score 3):

You do not need regular expressions; a simpler `LIKE` may do the work:

```
  select res_id
    from re_result
    where res_id like 'PSI%1'
```

The same thing can be done with regexp:

```
where regexp_like(res_id, '^PSI(.*)1$')
```

This matches `'PSI'` in the beginning of the string and `'1'` as last character, just before the end of string (`$`).
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) you find something more on regexp in Oracle

Comment: +1 for showing how this can be done without using regular expressions. Always to be preferred unless the query becomes too cumbersome and is easier to do by regular expression. (Of course, there are cases when there is ONLY a regexp solution; this is not one of them.)

Answer (score -1):

Another way to handle your query.

```
SELECT res_id FROM re_result WHERE UPPER(res_id) like UPPER('PSI%1')
```

Comment: This will match strings starting with 'psi', for example; given that the OP didn't ask that, it's better to explicitly explain this behaviour.